# Python program hangs when using multi-thread select sql query with MySQL db

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-workbench

I have a program like this:

```
def runBlockHash(i):
    #Somethings here#
    sql='SELECT * from abc where zzz=xyz' 
    mycursor.execute(sql, hashTree)
    results = mycursor.fetchall()
    #Something more here##

print("Connecting to SQL DB")
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host=args['hostname'],
    user=args['username'],
    passwd=args['password'],
    database=args['database']
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()


p=mp.Pool(2) #Define Number of Process to Use
p.map(runBlockHash,range(len(files_to_process))) # Call the function
p.close() #Close the multi threads
p.join()
```

But the problem I am facing is, when i have more than 1 CPU, not even a single sql query is executed. Python program just freeze.

I just want to run `select` statements. I don't want to insert or update the database.

Comment: Just a guess: Using a forked DB cursor for both subprocesses looks problematic. Maybe it should be created and closed in `runBlockHash`.

Comment: That will make the program slow, any workaround @MichaelButscher

Comment: One option is to give each "runBlockHash" a list of numbers instead of a single one to process per call. Another way is the "initializer" parameter of the "Pool". The initializer function can create the cursor once in each subprocess.